# Two lists of dictionaries with some different keys, how to find intersection?

Tags: python, list

My data looks like this:

```
buffer = [{"siteid": 1 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "545"}, {"siteid": 2 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "55"}, {"siteid": 2 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "55"}, {"siteid": 3 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "546"}]
layer = [{"siteid": 2 }, {"siteid": 4 }, {"siteid": 3 }]
```

I would like to be able to return all of the members of the buffer list where the siteid is the same.

The result would be:

```
[{"siteid": 2 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "55"}, {"siteid": 2 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "55"}, {"siteid": 3 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "546"}]
```

TIA,
Chris

Comment: The same as what? What's the layer list for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
buffer = [{"siteid": 1 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "545"}, {"siteid": 2 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "55"}, {"siteid": 2 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "55"}, {"siteid": 3 , "distance": 2, "codes": "1|b|c", "urv": "546"}]
layer = [{"siteid": 2 }, {"siteid": 4 }, {"siteid": 3 }]
ids = [l['siteid'] for l in layer]
print [b for b in buffer if b['siteid'] in ids]
```

Comment: Prefer list comprehensions to `filter`: `[x for x in buffer if x['siteid'] in ids]`

Comment: Fair enough - not sure why I used filter here - I normally use list comprehensions. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any builtin that could do this, but you could try writing your own function to find the intersection of your two dicts:

```
def find_intersection(buffer, layer):
    siteids = [a['siteid'] for a in layer]
    return [item for item in buffer if item['siteid'] in siteids]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intersection = set(x['sideid'] for x in buffer) & set(x['siteid'] for x in layer)
return [x for x in buffer if x['sideid'] in intersection]
```